# Nil value: no issue when visiting edit view but causing error when fired 'render edit'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

`User` has a `many-to-many` relationship with `Organization` through `Relationship`. The `User` table contains a `default_relationship_id`, which can also be `nil`.

In the `edit` view with the user's profile there's a dropdown box from which the user can select a relationship as default. All of this works.

Now consider the following specific scenario: user has no value for `default_relationship_id` and visits his `edit` page. If it then submits valid data, it works. However, if user submits invalid data and then `render edit` gets fired from the controller. This produces an error `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass` referring to the dropdown box. This error is not there if `default_relationship_id` its value wasn't `nil` in the first place.

Why does `render edit` fail because of this `nil` value, while is it possible to visit the edit view? And how to deal with this?

---

Migration:

```
t.integer  :default_relationship_id
```

Only model validation for `default_relationship_id` applies to when it is not `nil`.

Code in the view:

```
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="default_relationship_id">Default</label> 
<div class="col-md-8">
  <%= f.collection_select :default_relationship_id, @relationships, :id, :name, {}, {class: 'form-control input-md'} %>
</div>
```

Controller method:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @relationships = @user.relationships.where('member = ?', true)
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(strong_params)
    flash[:success] = "Updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: It could be awesome if you can show us some code instead of verbal description .

Comment: Thanks, added code to the OP.

Comment: And add the exact error message too.

Comment: you have to reinitialize all the variables that you had initialized in the edit action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize @relationships variable in the else branch:

```
 def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(strong_params)
    flash[:success] = "Updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @relationships = @user.relationships.where(member: true)
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Or to avoid duplication you can leave your action along and adjust your view instead:

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
   <%= f.collection_select :default_relationship_id, @user.relationships.where(member: true), :id, :name, {}, {class: 'form-control input-md'} %>
 </div>
```

In this case you can also remove "@relationships = @user.relationships.where('member = ?', true)" from your edit and probably show method.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I thought it would be sufficient to define it in `def edit` but I understand the render only renders the view and doesn't "re-fire" the `edit` method.

Comment: @Marty: you understood it correctly. I also added some code optimization for you to move this into the view. Also, you can extract this part of the code "@user.relationships.where(member: true)" into a helper, like: def user_memeber_relations(user) user.relationships.where(member: true); end

Comment: @Gen I would rather not query on the views, and handle it on the controller.    I assume it is a better practice

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff: well, in ideal world you probably would separate your UI from rails back end, and implement only an API in rails controllers and would pass json to your UI written in AngularJS or whatever. In real world, you often do in your view stuff like that user.address.city. That call is also a query (if you had not done some eager loading). You do association.any? in your views too, which also a query. So, to be clear, yes, it is not the best practice, but you are the owner of your code, and you should decide how to organize it and understand why you made this or that decision.